# Phusion Passenger + Heroku + Cloudfront: CORS Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, passenger, cors

I have fonts served from cdn.myapp.com using Cloudfront.

I was using the [font_assets](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) gem which helped me sending CORS headers to have my fonts accepted in Firefox (among others).

I recently moved my webserver to Phusion Passenger, I'm very happy with this (speed!).

But since my migration, I can't send these headers and I suspect nginx to be responsible for it.

How can I send custom headers with Phusion on Heroku? Can I access nginx config from heroku, or is there another config to set?

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the `rack-cors` gem but it took me a while to notice that although using Heroku's `Rails 12 Factor Gem` Phusion Passenger 5.0.10 (Nginx) was serving the assets.

Just for future reference, based on [@user664833's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945419/how-do-i-configure-access-control-allow-origin-with-rails-and-nginx/25977267#25977267), here's my setup for running a Rails 4.2 application hosted on Heroku with Phusion Passenger as server and Amazon Cloudfront as CDN, using cdn.my-domain.com as a CNAME for the distribution and restricting only to `GET` and `HEAD` requests for subdomains of  `my-domain.com`:

```
# config/nginx.conf.erb
location @static_asset {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  add_header ETag "";
  # added configuration for CORS for font assets
  if ($http_origin ~* ((https?:\/\/[^\/]*\.my-domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true'; # only needed for SSL
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
  }
  # end of added configuration
}
```

I edited the cache behavior to whitelist the `Origin` header.

[image: Forward headers option]

And changed the Origin Settings (Origin tab) to `Match viewer` (in case you want to use SSL).
[image: Match viewer option]

Finally, create an invalidation (no need to do this if it is a new configuration) in the Invalidations tab, using `/*` to clear everything.

Hopefully, this will save time to someone.

Comment: Hello, I have configured everyting you suggested but I am still getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. Nginx&Passenger works as expected. I configured cloudfront as well but no luck

Answer (score 0):

As from now, there is no option for this in the app config.

This discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/nskVxnxFssA
explains that this will be possible *in a near future*.

Comment: Have you solved this? [Here is my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25977267/664833). Please let me know if you have a better `nginx` configuration in this regard.

Comment: I found a way around since. Apparently they made a change on Phusion to make it work: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/nskVxnxFssA/Ov6FnRhzhZIJ Thanks for yours!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. What does your `nginx.conf.erb` look like with respect to the `Access-Control` lines? Is it exactly like mine or how is it different?

Comment: I haven't been using this solution yet. Cool that you reported!