# How do I configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with rails, nginx and passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, http-headers, cors, passenger

I cannot get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to show up in Chrome - my ultimate goal is to configure CORS for fonts with Rails, so it works in `production` with CloudFront. For now though, I just want to get it to work in `development`. I can see the header via `curl`, but not Chrome.

I am using `Rails 4.0`, and I have tried all of the following...

I have configured `Gemfile` and `application.rb` as per [the rack-cors example for rails 4](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/examples/rails4/config/application.rb):

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 0.2.9', require: 'rack/cors'
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.insert_before 'ActionDispatch::Static', 'Rack::Cors' do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
            :headers => :any,
            :methods => [:get, :options, :head]
    end
end
```

**rails console**

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"
2.0.0-p481 :002 > Hello::Application.config.serve_static_assets
 => true
```

**bash**

```
curl -i http://localhost:5000/assets/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff

Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 22660
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 23:51:57 GMT
ETag: "467b34801137bd4031e139839ad86370"
X-Request-Id: c4b07b4d-1c43-44ea-9565-dfda66378f98
X-Runtime: 0.046007
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.50
Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 04:39:38 UTC
Server: nginx/1.6.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.50

curl -i -H "Origin: http://localhost:5000" http://localhost:5000/assets/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff

Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 22660
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 23:51:57 GMT
ETag: "467b34801137bd4031e139839ad86370"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000   # adding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD     # -H
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000                      # produced
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true               # these
Vary: Origin                                         # headers
X-Request-Id: b9666f30-416d-4b5b-946a-bdd432bc191c
X-Runtime: 0.050420
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.50
Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 03:45:30 UTC
Server: nginx/1.6.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.50
```

**Chrome (v37) Developer Tools > Network > OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff > Headers > Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: ac153b8c-e0cb-489d-94dd-90aacc10d715
X-Runtime: 0.116511
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.50
Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 03:41:53 UTC
Server: nginx/1.6.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.50
```

I also tried the following alternatives, as per [various sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538549/cant-get-rack-cors-working-in-rails-application):

```
config.middleware.insert_before 'ActionDispatch::Static', 'Rack::Cors' do
config.middleware.insert_after Rails::Rack::Logger, Rack::Cors do
config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Rack::Cors do
config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Cors do
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
```

I also tried the following to `applications.rb`, as per [How to Display FontAwesome in Firefox Using Rails and CloudFront](https://derikulous.github.io/year/11/16/how-to-fontawesome/):

```
config.assets.header_rules = {
  :global => {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=31536000'},
  :fonts  => {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'}
}
```

I also tried the following in `config.ru`, as per [CloudFront CDN with Rails on Heroku](http://singlebrook.com/blog/cloudfront-cdn-with-rails-on-heroku)

```
require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :get 
    end 
end
```

**bundle exec rake middleware**

```
use Rack::Cors
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007f9ec21590b0>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
run Hello::Application.routes
```

I also tried [font_assets](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Server` line made me think that perhaps the assets are not being handled by Rails, but rather by `nginx`:

[image]

This means that the headers must be added by `nginx`, not Rails, and therefore we need to configure `nginx`. It turns out that [the ability to configure `nginx` is possible as of Passenger 4.0.39](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/nskVxnxFssA/Ov6FnRhzhZIJ) - ([here is the corresponding Git diff](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/a23671b677ca340209328951edb607fe348f3b1c)). The corresponding documentation is available in [Passenger Standalone, under Advanced configuration](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#advanced_configuration).

An important note in the documentation: *The original configuration template file may change from time to time, e.g. because new features are introduced into Phusion Passenger. If your configuration template file does not contain the required changes, then these new features may not work properly. In the worst case, Standalone might even malfunction. Therefore, every time you upgrade Phusion Passenger, you should check whether the original configuration template file has changed, and merge back any changes into your own file.*

With respect to that note, in addition to the customizable copy of the configuration file, create an "original" copy that you can `diff` whenever you upgrade Passenger.

**bash**

```
cp $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb config/nginx.conf.erb
cp config/nginx.conf.erb config/nginx.conf.erb.original
```

Next, add `--nginx-config-template config/nginx.conf.erb` to the `web` line in `Procfile`.

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3 --nginx-config-template config/nginx.conf.erb
```

**config/nginx.conf.erb**

Next, edit the configuration file `config/nginx.conf.erb` by finding a block that looks as follows:

```
    location @static_asset {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
    }
```

...and add the two `Access-Control` lines:

```
    location @static_asset {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Request-Method *;
    }
```

That's it. This will work in `production`, but not in `development`, due to `config.assets` differences between the two.

**the config diff**

The `diff` should not return anything now, but if any future updates to passenger include a change to this file, you will know.

```
diff $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb config/nginx.conf.erb.original
```

**nginx documentation**

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

**future improvements**

- restrict the `Allow-Origin`
- restrict the `Request-Method`
- restrict both headers to just fonts

Answer (score 3):

YES!  Finally.

user664833's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25977267/5355691) is great, except I couldn't find my Passenger config file to edit.

Thomas Nye's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927940/5355691) gives the full file to create at config/nginx.conf.erb:

```
    ##########################################################################
#  Passenger Standalone is built on the same technology that powers
#  Passenger for Nginx, so any configuration option supported by Passenger
#  for Nginx can be applied to Passenger Standalone as well. You can do
#  this by direct editing the Nginx configuration template that is used by
#  Passenger Standalone.
#
#  This file is the original template. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
#  Instead, make a copy of this file and pass the `--nginx-config-template`
#  parameter to Passenger Standalone.
#
#  Learn more about using the Nginx configuration template at:
#  https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
#
#  *** NOTE ***
#  If you customize the template file, make sure you keep an eye on the
#  original template file and merge any changes. New Phusion Passenger
#  features may require changes to the template file.
##############################################################

<%= include_passenger_internal_template('global.erb') %>

worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('http.erb', 4) %>

    ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
    # This is a good place to put your own config
    # options. Note that your options must not
    # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
    # Learn more at:
    # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

    ### END your own configuration options ###

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
        # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
        server {
            <%= include_passenger_internal_template('mass_deployment_default_server.erb', 12) %>
        }
    <% end %>

    <% for app in @apps %>
    server {
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('server.erb', 8, true, binding) %>
        <%# <%= include_passenger_internal_template('rails_asset_pipeline.erb', 8, false) %1> %>

        ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
        # This is a good place to put your own config
        # options. Note that your options must not
        # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
        # Learn more at:
        # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
        # Rails asset pipeline support.
        location ~ "^/assets/.+-([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})\..+" {
            error_page 490 = @static_asset;
            error_page 491 = @dynamic_request;
            recursive_error_pages on;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                return 490;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 491;
            }
        }
        location @static_asset {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
            if ($http_origin ~* ((https?:\/\/[^\/]*\.herokuapp\.com(:[0-9]+)?))) {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
            }
        }
        location @dynamic_request {
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        ### END your own configuration options ###
    }
    passenger_pre_start <%= listen_url(app) %>;
    <% end %>

    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('footer.erb', 4) %>
}
```

`Procfile` should include the line:

`web:         bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3 --nginx-config-template config/nginx.conf.erb`

You'll also need to configure you Cloudfront CDN that is serving the assets as per [Guapolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083809/5355691)

[image: Configure CORS Cloudfront]

In your distribution that is giving you the CORS grief, go to the behaviours tab, and a new behaviour, selecting the path to the asset, i.e. /assets/icons.ttf and whitelist 'Origin' as per the above image.

You may also need, in you distribution, to 'invalidate' the old cached resource, in the invalidations tab, i.e. put in the full asset and cached name from your inspector, and invalidate.  Once that has processed, deploy the app  with the config and restart heroku. You'll need to open inspector and 'empty cache and hard reload' the page.

Hopefully that works - it sounds like the passenger config changes every now and then, so we may find this breaks and the answer will need to be updated to reflect the new config.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it is answer, but it looks like you also could try the easiest way with using `after_filter` with:

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
...
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for headers setting in nginx. Rails does the job.

```rb
# initializers/cors.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Avoid CORS issues when API is called from the frontend app.
# Handle Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in order to accept cross-origin AJAX requests.

# Read more: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head]
  end
end
```

```
# nginx.conf
...

upstream rails_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

...

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;

  # send non-static file requests to the app server  
  location / {    
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;    
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;         
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;    
    proxy_redirect off;    
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;  
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try these solutions or a combination:

1. http://ryanwood.com/2014/09/03/a-chrome-update-breaks-cdn-fonts/
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html
3. http://github.com/ericallam/font_assets