# Rails Passenger Glyphicon CORS Cloudfront NGINX Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cors, passenger, amazon-cloudfront

So I am aware that stackoverflow is wrought with these questions about CORS Nginx, Cloudfront and Heroku but for some reason I can't get it to work. I have been following this question's answer:

[How do I configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with rails, nginx and passenger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945419/how-do-i-configure-access-control-allow-origin-with-rails-and-nginx)

However I can't seem to figure out where to put the custom code block:

> ```
> config/nginx.conf.erb
> ```
>
> Next, edit the configuration file config/nginx.conf.erb by finding a
>   block that looks as follows:
>
> ```
> location @static_asset {
>     gzip_static on;
>     expires max;
>     add_header Cache-Control public;
>     add_header ETag "";
> } ...and add the two Access-Control lines:
> ```
>
> to

```
>     location @static_asset {
>         gzip_static on;
>         expires max;
>         add_header Cache-Control public;
>         add_header ETag "";
>         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
>         add_header Access-Control-Request-Method *;
>     } That's it. This will work in production, but not in development, due to config.assets differences between the two.
```

in my Nginx configuration. I am using Phusion Passenger 5.0.23. The Nginx config doesnt have a location @static_asset block in the one that I pulled from passenger. It does have a section for custom configurations but that hasnt worked for me. My glyphicons continue to show up as boxes How do I get it to work?
I have also tried this
[Phusion Passenger + Heroku + Cloudfront: CORS Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487079/phusion-passenger-heroku-cloudfront-cors-configuration)

Current Config File

```
    ##########################################################################
#  Passenger Standalone is built on the same technology that powers
#  Passenger for Nginx, so any configuration option supported by Passenger
#  for Nginx can be applied to Passenger Standalone as well. You can do
#  this by direct editing the Nginx configuration template that is used by
#  Passenger Standalone.
#
#  This file is the original template. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
#  Instead, make a copy of this file and pass the `--nginx-config-template`
#  parameter to Passenger Standalone.
#
#  Learn more about using the Nginx configuration template at:
#  https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
#
#  *** NOTE ***
#  If you customize the template file, make sure you keep an eye on the
#  original template file and merge any changes. New Phusion Passenger
#  features may require changes to the template file.
##############################################################

<%= include_passenger_internal_template('global.erb') %>

worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('http.erb', 4) %>



    ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
    # This is a good place to put your own config
    # options. Note that your options must not
    # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
    # Learn more at:
    # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

    ### END your own configuration options ###

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
        # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
        server {
            <%= include_passenger_internal_template('mass_deployment_default_server.erb', 12) %>
        }
    <% end %>

    <% for app in @apps %>
    server {
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('server.erb', 8, true, binding) %>
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('rails_asset_pipeline.erb', 8, false) %>

        ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
        # This is a good place to put your own config
        # options. Note that your options must not
        # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
        # Learn more at:
        # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

        # CloudFront fix 
        location /public/* {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Request-Method *;
        }


        ### END your own configuration options ###
    }
    passenger_pre_start <%= listen_url(app) %>;
    <% end %>
}
```

Comment: is @static_asset  set? does anybody know what sets this?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I have hardcoded it in at the moment it still isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this config worked for me:

```
    ##########################################################################
#  Passenger Standalone is built on the same technology that powers
#  Passenger for Nginx, so any configuration option supported by Passenger
#  for Nginx can be applied to Passenger Standalone as well. You can do
#  this by direct editing the Nginx configuration template that is used by
#  Passenger Standalone.
#
#  This file is the original template. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
#  Instead, make a copy of this file and pass the `--nginx-config-template`
#  parameter to Passenger Standalone.
#
#  Learn more about using the Nginx configuration template at:
#  https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
#
#  *** NOTE ***
#  If you customize the template file, make sure you keep an eye on the
#  original template file and merge any changes. New Phusion Passenger
#  features may require changes to the template file.
##############################################################

<%= include_passenger_internal_template('global.erb') %>

worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('http.erb', 4) %>

    ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
    # This is a good place to put your own config
    # options. Note that your options must not
    # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
    # Learn more at:
    # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

    ### END your own configuration options ###

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
        # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
        server {
            <%= include_passenger_internal_template('mass_deployment_default_server.erb', 12) %>
        }
    <% end %>

    <% for app in @apps %>
    server {
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('server.erb', 8, true, binding) %>
        <%# <%= include_passenger_internal_template('rails_asset_pipeline.erb', 8, false) %1> %>

        ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
        # This is a good place to put your own config
        # options. Note that your options must not
        # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
        # Learn more at:
        # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
        # Rails asset pipeline support.
        location ~ "^/assets/.+-([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})\..+" {
            error_page 490 = @static_asset;
            error_page 491 = @dynamic_request;
            recursive_error_pages on;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                return 490;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 491;
            }
        }
        location @static_asset {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
            if ($http_origin ~* ((https?:\/\/[^\/]*\.herokuapp\.com(:[0-9]+)?))) {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
            }
        }
        location @dynamic_request {
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        ### END your own configuration options ###
    }
    passenger_pre_start <%= listen_url(app) %>;
    <% end %>

    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('footer.erb', 4) %>
}
```